# Command.execute is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

The error I get:

> TypeError: command.execute is not a function
> at Object.execute (C:\Users\lachl\Desktop\Coding\Discord Bot\src\events\client\interactionCreate.js:11:25)
> at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lachl\Desktop\Coding\Discord Bot\src\functions\handlers\handleEvents.js:15:63)
> at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)

handleEvents.js file:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = (client) => {
  client.handleEvents = async () => {
    const eventFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/events`);
    for (const folder of eventFolders) {
      const eventFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`./src/events/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
    switch (folder) {
        case 'client':
            for (const file of eventFiles) {
                const event = require(`../../events/${folder}/${file}`);
                if (event.once) client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
                else client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
            }
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    }
  };
};
```

interactionCreate.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "interactionCreate",
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
      const { commands } = client;
      const { commandName } = interaction;
      const command = commands.get(commandName);
      if (!command) return;

      try {
          await command.execute(interaction, client);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({
          content: `Something went wrong while executing this command...`,
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      }
    }
  },
};
```

handleCommands.js file:

```js
const { REST } = require("@discordjs/rest");
const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = (client) => {
  client.handleCommands = async () => {
    const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/commands`);
    for (const folder of commandFolders) {
      const commandFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`./src/commands/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

      const { commands, commandArray } = client;
      for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`../../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
        console.log(
          `Command ${command.data.name} has passed through the handler`
        );
      }
    }

    const clientId = "1050985494537834606";
    const guildId = "1041260203112411197";
    const rest = new REST({ version: "9" }).setToken(process.env.token);
    try {
      console.log("Started refreshing application [/] commands");

      await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), {
        body: client.commandArray,
      });

      console.log("Successfully reloaded application [/] commands.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
};
```

ping.js file:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
       .setName('ping')
       .setDescription("Ping Command!"),
    async exectute(interaction, client) {
        const message = await interaction.deferReply({
            fetchReply: true
        });
        
        const newMessage = `API LATENCY: ${client.ws.ping}\nClient Ping: ${message.createdTimeStamp - interaction.createdTimeStamp}`
        await interaction.editReply({
            content: newMessage
        });  
    
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the bot goes online but when I try to run a command, it doesn't work

Comment: Typo, `exectute` should be `execute` in `ping.js`

Answer (score -1):

You misspelled execute in ping.js.